# OpenCV C++/Obj-C: goodFeaturesToTrack inside specific blob

Tags: opencv, blob, filtering, contour

Is there a quick solution to specify the ROI only within the contours of the blob I'm intereseted in?

My ideas so far:

1. Using the boundingRect, but it contains too much stuff I don't want to analyse.
2. Applying goodFeaturesToTrack to the whole image and then loop through the output coordinates to eliminate the once outside my blobs contour

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I found what I need: cv::pointPolygonTest() seems to be the right thing, but I'm not sure how to implement it …

Here's some code:

```
// ...
IplImage forground_ipl = result;
IplImage *labelImg = cvCreateImage(forground.size(), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1);

CvBlobs blobs;
bool found = cvb::cvLabel(&forground_ipl, labelImg, blobs);
IplImage *imgOut = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&forground_ipl), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);

if (found) {
    vb::CvBlob *greaterBlob = blobs[cvb::cvGreaterBlob(blobs)];
    cvb::cvRenderBlob(labelImg, greaterBlob, &forground_ipl, imgOut);
    CvContourPolygon *polygon = cvConvertChainCodesToPolygon(&greaterBlob->contour);
}
```

"polygon" contains the contour I need.

goodFeaturesToTrack is implemented this way:

```
- (std::vector<cv::Point2f>)pointsFromGoodFeaturesToTrack:(cv::Mat &)_image
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
    cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(_image,corners, 100, 0.01, 10);
    return corners;
}
```

So next I need to loop through the corners and check each point with cv::pointPolygonTest(), right?

Comment: Can you draw a quick example of what you want?

Comment: @mevatron I got the contours of the carton (other thread) with your help and cvBlob, now I fire goodFeaturesToTrack on the input image to get the corners of the carton I'm interested in. Next step is filtering the corners to only get the once inside the carton contour. Hope you get what I want to do …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a mask over your interest region:

**EDIT**
How to make a mask:

Make a mask;

```
Mat mask(origImg.size(), CV_8UC1);
mask.setTo(Scalar::all(0));
// here I assume your contour is extracted with findContours, 
// and is stored in a vector<vector<Point>> 
// and that you know which contour is the blob
// if it's not the case, use fillPoly instead of drawContour();
Scalar color(255,255,255); // white. actually, it's monchannel.
drawContours(mask, contours, contourIdx, color );

// fillPoly(Mat& img, const Point** pts, const int* npts, 
//         int ncontours, const Scalar& color)
```

And now you're ready to use it. **BUT**, look carefully at the result -  I have heard about some bugs in OpenCV regarding the mask parameter for feature extractors, and I am not sure if it's about this one.

```
// note the mask parameter:

void goodFeaturesToTrack(InputArray image, OutputArray corners, int maxCorners, 
    double qualityLevel, double minDistance, 
    InputArray mask=noArray(), int blockSize=3, 
    bool useHarrisDetector=false, double k=0.04 )
```

This will also improve the speed of your aplication - goodFeaturesToTrack eats a hoge amount of time, and if you apply it only on a smaller image, the overall gain is significant.

Comment: Thanks that's a good point! But I dont know how to convert the CvContourPolygon to an OpenCV conform InputArray …